# I want to merge 2 layers using script-fu code

Tags: gimp, script-fu

I am new to script-fu in gimp.
I want to merge 2 layers using script-fu code. But I don't know how to write down the function. Can you help me write the (.scm) function for me

Answer (score 0):

(define (layers-to-psd image-path psd-path)
(let*
(
(image (car (gimp-file-load RUN-NONINTERACTIVE image-path image-path)))
(number-of-layers layer (car (gimp-file-load-layer RUN-NONINTERACTIVE image image-path)))

```
)
(define merged(car gimp-image-merge-layer-group image layer image-path)
(file-psd-save RUN-NONINTERACTIVE image merged psd-path psd-path 1 0)
(gimp-image-delete image)
```

)
)
)

save above code in layers-to-psd.scm and Run using following command:
gimp -i -c -b '(layers-to-psd "image/path" "output/psd/path")' -b '(gimp-quit 0)'